# Se puede abrir una imagen usando background-image en forma de modal (como ventana)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy tratando de crear una experiencia interactiva en la que al hacer clic en una imagen de fondo (definida con background-image), esta se abra como una ventana modal, permitiendo una vista más grande y la posibilidad de cerrarla. Sin embargo, hasta el momento, no lo he logrado que esta funcionalidad funcione como espero.

Intentó diversas soluciones, incluido el uso de JavaScript y CSS, pero parece que algo no está en su lugar. ¿Alguien podría proporcionarme orientación sobre cómo lograr este comportamiento deseado?

mi html

```
<section class="cartas">
  <div class="cartas__contenedor">
    <div class="cartas__contenedor-imagen cart1">
      <button class="cartas__contenedor-botoneliminar" type="button">
        <img
          class="cartas__contenedor-eliminarimagen"
          src="imagenes/borrarfoto.svg"
          alt="Eliminar"
        />
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="tarjetas">
      <h2 class="cartas__contenedor-texto">Valle de Yosemite</h2>
      <button class="cora" type="button">
        <img class="like" src="imagenes/megusta.svg" alt="Me gusta" />
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cartas__contenedor">
    <div class="cartas__contenedor-imagen cart2">
      <button class="cartas__contenedor-botoneliminar" type="button">
        <img
          class="cartas__contenedor-eliminarimagen"
          src="imagenes/borrarfoto.svg"
          alt="Eliminar"
        />
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="tarjetas">
      <h2 class="cartas__contenedor-texto">Lago Louise</h2>
      <button class="cora" type="button">
        <img class="like" src="imagenes/megusta.svg" alt="Me gusta" />
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cartas__contenedor">
    <div class="cartas__contenedor-imagen cart3">
      <button class="cartas__contenedor-botoneliminar" type="button">
        <img
          class="cartas__contenedor-eliminarimagen"
          src="imagenes/borrarfoto.svg"
          alt="Eliminar"
        />
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="tarjetas">
      <h2 class="cartas__contenedor-texto">Montañas Calvas</h2>
      <button class="cora" type="button">
        <img class="like" src="imagenes/megusta.svg" alt="Me gusta" />
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
 <div id="modalimage" class="modalimage">
  <span class="cerrar" onclick="cerrarModal()">&times;</span>
  <img id="imagenModal" class="modal-contenido" />
</div>
```

este es mi html aqui tengo 3 tarjetas que son 3 imagenes tiene un boton de like y otro de borrar pero eso ya lo tengo el problema es que cuando le doy click a la imagen quisiera que se abra como modal(ventana). las iamgenes las agregue en el css

mi CSS

```
    .cart1 {
  background-image: url("../imagenes/foto1.jpeg");
}
.cart2 {
  background-image: url("../imagenes/foto2.jpeg");
}
.cart3 {
  background-image: url("../imagenes/foto3.jpeg");
}
```

asi ingrese las imagenes en el CSS pero quisiera que cuando yo le de click a  la imagen se abra en forma de ventana intentado de todo pero no me resulta aqui mi javascript.

```
const cartas = document.querySelectorAll(".cart1, .cart2, .cart3");

cartas.forEach(function (carta) {
  carta.addEventListener("click", function () {
    mostrarModal(carta);
  });
});

function mostrarModal(carta) {
  // Obtén el modal y la imagen del modal
  var modal = document.getElementById("modalimage");
  var modalImg = document.getElementById("imagenModal");

  // Muestra el modal y establece la imagen del modal
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.style.backgroundImage = carta.style.backgroundImage;
```

Comment: oki ya lo voy a corregir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const like = document.querySelectorAll(".like");

like.forEach(function (button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function () {

if (button.classList.contains("dislike")) {
  button.classList.remove("dislike");
} else {
  button.classList.add("dislike");
}
  });
});
```

ahi me funciono

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Puede que entiendas qué hace, pero otros usuarios que podrían llegar a tener un problema similar, puede que no.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer la propiedad `backgroundImage` no te esta llegando a traves de `element.style`, prueba usando [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) que devuelve los estilos finales computados del elemento pasado por parámetros.

Aunque `style` y `getComputedStyle()` parezcan lo mismo, el primero se usa para modificar los estilos y el segundo es de solo lectura y debería usarse para obtener estilos de cierto elemento de forma fiable:

```
function mostrarModal(carta) {
  // Obtén el modal y la imagen del modal
  var modal = document.getElementById("modalimage");
  var modalImg = document.getElementById("imagenModal");

  // Muestra el modal y establece la imagen del modal
  modal.style.display = "block";
  let url = getComputedStyle(carta).backgroundImage
  modalImg.style.backgroundImage = url;
}
```